# compatibility and possible problems with my basic div slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have  never used or developed any slider for webpage yet and this is my first time.So I searched for a tutorial and found one where he was using the following JQuery code to silde the `div`s on webpage.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('#controls').on('click', 'span', function(){
            $("#inner_container").css("transform","translateX("+$(this).index() * -450+"px)");
          });
        })
```

Since I had single slider on page and there was no requirement of `jQuery` for any other purpose,I decided not to use `JQuery` and thus changed the script to

```
function slide(i)
        {
            document.getElementById("inner_container").style.transform="translateX("+(i*-450)+"px)"
        }
```

and called this function as

```
<div id="controls"><span onclick='slide(3);'>Show Third</span></div>
```

Its working fine but I wanted to know that is there any pitfall with this replacement as I am using this for navigation on my website and my entire site is dependent on it?

Comment: Have you checked [compatibility](http://caniuse.com/)?

Comment: everything you can do with jQuery you can do it without it, so it is just a matter of trying and if it fails, debugging it...    Maybe the spaghetti code in the last code snippet could be avoided by adding a click handler but otherwise it seems fine...

Comment: can you provide a JSFiddle ?